# symlink installed java to /usr/java/latest

Tags: linux, bash

A program requires a java directory location of `/usr/java/latest`. In many cases this directory does not exist. In order to get the program to run correctly I need to do the following steps:

```
mkdir -p /usr/java
mkdir -p /usr/java/latest
```

Then I need to find what java installations are available and symlink them to the above directories:

```
ll /usr/lib/jvm
```

I usually choose the latest directory avialable...ie:

```
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root   16 Feb 12  2016 java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.71-2.b15.el7_2.x86_64
```

and then create a link to /usr/java/latest

```
ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.71-2.b15.el7_2.x86_64/jre/lib /usr/java/latest/lib
ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.71-2.b15.el7_2.x86_64/jre/bin /usr/java/latest/bin
```

I am trying to create an installation script that automates the above process without having to copy and paste the directory name for the symbolic link. Basically I want to parse the /usr/lib/jvm/ directory for the most recent (or any) available java directory. Then I want to take that and link the lib and bin directories within that directory to the /usr/java/latest directory. Thank you in advance for any type of advice.

Comment: Instead of `ll` just do `ls`.

Comment: You've described what your want to do, but not what you're having trouble with. Please edit your question to actually contain a question. :) Also, I'd remove the java and centos tags; while the program you're symlinking happens to be java, this isn't actually a Java question as far as I can tell. And similarly, it doesn't seem like a centos-specific question.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the below to find the directory I need.

```
ls -F /usr/lib/jvm | grep / | sed '$!d' | sed 's:/*$::'
```